# Recently attended one interview. Unable to answer this one, can you help me out

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, data-modeling

Let's say there are two tables names like

- Table-A has two columns  col1,col2.
- Table-B has two columns col3,col4.

`col1` is primary key, `col3` is foreign key dependent on `col1`. `col4` is primary key, `col2` is foreign key dependent on `col4`. So, both the tables are dependent on each other.

Now, I want to insert a record into `table-A`. How can I do this (in oracle 11g)?

Answer (score 4):

You can defer the constraint evaluation until commit.

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_table_1 (col2 ) REFERENCES table_2( col4)
  INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
```

This will postpone the constraint checking to the committing time.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, you can't. That is, you cannot insert a record into `Table_A` without also inserting a record into `Table_B`.

**What the interviewer was probably hoping for:**

Given that we need to insert records into both tables simultaneously can we do that?

Nope: the `insert all` syntax will fail on `ORA-02291: integrity constraint WHATEVER_FK) violated - parent key not found`

```
insert all
   into table_a values (n1, n2)
   into table_b values (n2, n1)
select 23 as n1
       , 42 as n2
from dual
/
```

The workaround is to change the foreign keys so they are deferred:

```
alter table table_a add constraint ab_fk foreign key (col2)
     references table_b (col4) INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
alter table table_b add constraint ba_fk foreign key (col3)
     references table_a (col1) INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
```

**The correct answer (although only recommended for the most assured of candidates):**

Why are you asking me questions about a broken data model? Is this indicative of the sort of thing I'll be working with if I join your company?

Because this is a completely false situation. The two foreign keys operate to enforce a 1:1 relationship between `table_a` and `table_b`. So why are they two separate tables? Make them one and the problem goes away. This achieves the same thing:

```
alter table table_a add constraint ab_uk unique (col2);
drop table table_b;
```

Supposing there is a genuine need for two tables (i.e. if there are more columns than appear in this example) chose one table to be the parent and make the other one the child. Because as soon as we express the model that way we understand why it's so wrong: no child is its own parent, not even in the most twisted of sci-fi tales.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just ensure that Col2 contains a value from Col4 of Table-B and that Col1 doesn't already exist in Table-A.  Not knowing anything about the data types of the columns involved does make it more difficult, but since there doesn't seem to be an restrictions on how you get the data this might work:

```
insert into TableA select max(col1)||'0', max(col2) from TableA ;
```

This will work as long as col1 is either numeric or character based.  It will likely fail if col1 is some other data type.