# Can there be a 1 to 1 relationship for keys with multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I am creating web-app for database management. Database can be created using diagrams ER.
Here is screen from my app:
[image]

As you can see this pseudo example shows 4x types of cases:
1) Primary key --> Primary key  (1:1)
2) Unique key --> Unique key (1:1)
3) Primary key consisting of two fields --> Primary key consisting of two fields (1:1)
4) Unique key consisting of two fields --> Unique key consisting of two fields (1:1)

And here is my question:
**Is it all true?** I wonder about these double keys... Is this really a 1 to 1 relation?
**Generally, I wonder about these first 2 cases too. Are there also true?**

MySQL Workbench shows it is not true:
[image]

I dont know why but you can see MySQL Workbench shows this is one to many relation...

Oracle Sql Developer:
[image]

**Can anyone tell me when 1 to 1 relationship actually is?**
Documentation shows i have right:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/RepositoryGuide/html/s1204onetoonewithauxiliarytable01.html
but diagrams ER in MySQL Workbench and Sql Developer shows something different...

SQL code from that tables:

```
CREATE USER "Student" IDENTIFIED BY "null";

CREATE TABLE "Student".Table1 (
    PK_FK NUMBER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table2 (
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table3 (
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    UK_FK NUMBER
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table4 (
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    UK NUMBER
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table5 (
    PK_1_FK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PK_2_FK NUMBER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table6 (
    PK_1 NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PK_2 NUMBER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table7 (
    UK_1_FK NUMBER,
    UK_2_FK NUMBER
);
CREATE TABLE "Student".Table8 (
    UK_1 NUMBER,
    UK_2 NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE "Student".Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK_FK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT Table2_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT Table3_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table4 ADD CONSTRAINT Table4_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table5 ADD CONSTRAINT Table5_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK_1_FK, PK_2_FK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table6 ADD CONSTRAINT Table6_PK PRIMARY KEY (PK_1, PK_2);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT Table3_UK1 UNIQUE (UK_FK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table4 ADD CONSTRAINT Table4_UK2 UNIQUE (UK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table7 ADD CONSTRAINT Table7_UK3 UNIQUE (UK_1_FK, UK_2_FK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table8 ADD CONSTRAINT Table8_UK4 UNIQUE (UK_1, UK_2);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (PK_FK)
REFERENCES "Student".Table2 (PK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table3 ADD CONSTRAINT Table3_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (UK_FK)
REFERENCES "Student".Table4 (UK);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table5 ADD CONSTRAINT Table5_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (PK_1_FK, PK_2_FK)
REFERENCES "Student".Table6 (PK_1, PK_2);
ALTER TABLE "Student".Table7 ADD CONSTRAINT Table7_FK4 FOREIGN KEY (UK_1_FK, UK_2_FK)
REFERENCES "Student".Table8 (UK_1, UK_2);
```

Comment: I am asking if the 1 to 1 relation actually occurs in 4x cases that I posted. I need to implement that.

Comment: Your first picture depicts four 1 to 1 relationships. To know for sure, you should post the primary and foreign key text from the ddl generated. Then we'd all know for sure. You could post *all* of the ddl commands but you only have to post the key information. Additionally, if you're unsure, then you can test the enforcement of the relationships by trying to insert rows that would violate the rules you want to enforce.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Jeff Holt, i  edited post, you can see sql code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-to-one relationship is still a master-detail relationship. One table is the owner of the identifier and the other table references it through a foreign key. This is the relationship show in the MySQL Workbench and SQL Developer pictures.

> Documentation shows i have right:

You link to Oracle's documentation for ATG Repository, which is a specialist tool for representing data generically, but even there we can see from the SQL that USER_TBL is the primary table and "owns" the ID column and JOB_TBL is the auxiliary table and references the ID.

```
CREATE TABLE usr_tbl (
        id                      VARCHAR(32)     not null,
        nam_col                 VARCHAR(32)     null,
        age_col                 INTEGER null,
        primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE job_tbl (
        id                      VARCHAR(32)     not null references usr_tbl(id),
        function                VARCHAR(32)     null,
        title                   VARCHAR(32)     null,
        primary key(id)
```

In other words, we can have a USER without a JOB but we can't have a JOB without a USER. But a USER can have only one JOB and one JOB belongs only to ONE user.

Your diagram is wrong because it renders TABLE7 and TABLE8 as peers. But foreign keys don't work like that. One table defer to the other. When I look at your notation I can't see whether TABLE8 owns TABLE7 or TABLE7 owns TABLE8. Whereas, it's quite clear in the MySQL and Oracle diagrams. The purpose of a data model is to clarify the database design not obfuscate it.

---

Note, it is perfectly possible to define two tables which have foreign keys that reference each other's primary key. The trick is insert data into them. This requires deferring the foreign key constraints. I view deferred constraints as a red flag, a sign of a broken data model.

Comment: Well I am not clearly understand why you think my tables 7 and 8 are rendered as peers. If i will delete "nam_col" and "age_col" from usr_tbl and also i will delete "function" and "title" from job_tbl. 
Are these tables won't look identical?

The only difference besides the double key is that I use the alter table

Comment: Well I looked at your notation and I can't see whether TABLE8 owns TABLE7 or TABLE7 owns TABLE8. It's quite clear in the MySQL and Oracle diagrams. The purpose of a data model is to **clarify** the database design not obfuscate it.

Comment: Ah... I finally understand your point. You think my diagram is simply illegible? In fact, that's what I really wanted to know. How should I mark it? As you can see, oracle uses an arrow that clearly shows who is the initiator of the relationship. Should I do the same?

Comment: There several existing [data model notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). Choose one and apply it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly possible. Here's an example for PostgreSQL:

```
create table t1 (
  a int not null,
  b int not null,
  constraint uq1 (a, b),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (a, b) references t2 (a, b)
    deferrable initially deferred
);

create table t2 (
  a int not null,
  b int not null,
  constraint uq2 (a, b),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (a, b) references t1 (a, b)
    deferrable initially deferred
);
```

In this case t1 (a,b) is unique and references t2 (a, b) that is also unique. That's a 1:1 relationship using "composite keys".

**Note**: This example uses "circular references" that is a *standard* part of SQL, but is only implemented [to my knowledge] by PostgreSQL and Oracle. It won't run in MySQL.

Comment: Now write the SQL which inserts a record into T1 and T2 :)

Comment: @APC Sure, but the inserts can only run in PostgreSQL and Oracle. You need to defer the constraint check to "transaction" level, instead of statement or row levels. Deferability is an integral part of the the SQL standard, but only implemented in these two databases. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300307/not-deferrable-versus-deferrable-initially-immediate/53747200#53747200

Comment: I always regard the need to defer constraints as a sign of a broken data model. See [my answer to an "interview question" question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270919/146325)

Comment: @APC I hear you. There's little use to this functionality and most of the time you probably want to keep a 1:1 relationship as a single table.